# Finding f'(a) of f(x) with limited information.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm a Calculus 1 tutor helping a student with their web-work (online homework problems). We came across a problem that asks exactly the following:

> "Find $f'(a)$ for
>
> $f(x) = -1/\sqrt{7-8x}$
>
> $f'(a)$ = ? "

That's all the information it gives, and it wont accept limit notation or any variable other than $a$ as part of the answer. If we don't have an $a$ to work with and we can't give the answer in terms of other variables or write it as a limit, how do they expect us to answer it? Am I missing something extremely obvious or is it just a poorly designed problem?

Comment: You calculate $f^\prime(x)$, then you replace $x$ with $a$, simple as it gets.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's just weirdly ordered then because they haven't gone over finding derivatives of functions yet, only finding the tangent lines of specific points. Guess we're skipping ahead a section.

Comment: You were correct. The answer they were looking for was f'(a) = -4/[(7-8a)^(3/2)]

How the teacher expected them to get there without having been taught the power rule is beyond me. I managed to hammer it out, but it was almost a page and a half of wonky algebra tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't take a page and a half, just multiplying once by the conjugate and using a light touch:

$$f'(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-1/\sqrt{a+h} + 1/\sqrt{a}}{h}$$ $$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(-1/\sqrt{a+h} + 1/\sqrt{a})(1/\sqrt{a+h} + 1/\sqrt{a})}{h(1/\sqrt{a+h} + 1/\sqrt{a})} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-1/(a+h) + 1/a}{h(1/\sqrt{a+h} + 1/\sqrt{a})}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h/(a+h)}{h(1/\sqrt{a+h} + 1/\sqrt{a})} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1/(a+h)}{1/\sqrt{a+h} + 1/\sqrt{a}} = \frac{1/a}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a}} = \frac{1}{2} a^{-3/2}$$

The difficulty is that one is probably tempted to collect terms prematurely—which is a valid method, but it increases the number of steps and the possibility of error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to find $f'(x)$ and then replace $x$ with $a$. It was just extremely difficult and convoluted to do with the tools the student had been taught. Oh well.